# Ruby Write in CSV file by columns from arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv

I would like generate a csv file from severals arrays.
This is my code:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open("csvfile.csv", "ab") do |csv|
csv << [array1]
csv << [array2]
csv << [array3]
end
```

i need this output format:

```
array1,array2,array3
array1,array2,array3
array1,array2,array3
array1,array2,array3
array1,array2,array3
```

Thx for you help

Answer (score 4):

According to your post, did you mean that array1, array2, array3 stores values of the 3 columns of the table, and the row index is identified by the index of the values in these arrays? You can first group the columns together, do a `transpose` on the 2-d array and then write to the CSV file row by row.

```rb
require 'csv'
table = [array1, array2, array3].transpose
CSV.open('csvfile.csv', 'ab') do |csv|
    table.each do |row|
        csv << row
    end
end
```

You'll get a csv file like this:

```
array1[0], array2[0], array3[0]
array1[1], array2[1], array3[1]
array1[2], array2[2], array3[2]
...
```

Comment: yes, that's what I wanted to do. Perfect! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) is the most common method for parallel traversal of multiple collections.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open('csvfile.csv', 'ab') do |csv|
  array1.zip(array2,array3) { |row| csv << row }
end
```